# Tinder like Animation using UIPanGestureRecognizer and Rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement [Tinder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tinder/id547702041) like animation to swipe an image to left and right and rotate it while doing so. I have an array of images and need swipe them one after the other.

So far I have been able to Use **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to move the image around but when I try to rotate the image, everything just breaks.

I have uploaded the code [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3995). Could someone point me out in the right direction to develop the algorithm and fine tune it to achieve the perfection like Tinder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by listening to **touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded** methods..

Basically this is what you need to do:

1. In **touchesBegan** get the touch point with respect to current view (You will need it later to rotate the image by anchoring at this point).
2. In **touchesMoved** get the touch point with respect to superview and move the view as the touches are moved.
3. Apply a small rotation based on the movement using **CGAffineTransformMakeRotation**
4. In **touchesEnded** either move the view offscreen or set it back to its initial position.

Hope this help.. Check this [repo](https://github.com/coolbeet/CBDraggableView) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

As Shri mentioned, you should handle pan gesture recognizers state. Here is the quick example of code

```
func panGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    xDistanceFromCenter = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self).x
        yDistanceFromCenter = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self).y

        let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)

        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .Began:
            originalLocation = center
            animationDirection = touchLocation.y >= frame.size.height / 2 ? -1.0 : 1.0
            break
        case .Changed:
            let rotationStrength = min(xDistanceFromCenter / self.frame.size.width, rotationMax)
            let rotationAngle = animationDirection * defaultRotationAngle * rotationStrength
            let scaleStrength = 1 - ((1 - scaleMin) * fabs(rotationStrength))
            let scale = max(scaleStrength, scaleMin)
            let transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle)
            let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale) 
            self.transform = scaleTransform
            break
        case .Ended:
            swipeMadeAction()
        default :
            break
        }
}
```

You can look at our implementation on this repo:
https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this recently for the company I work for and decided to open source it. https://github.com/skensell/MXCardsSwipingView

I used the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in combination with `UIAttachmentBehavior`. Introduced in iOS 7, it's conceptually easier and less code. It's like attaching your finger to that part of the `UIView`.

More details here: https://github.com/skensell/MXCardsSwipingView/blob/master/MXCardsSwipingView/Classes/MXCardsSwipingView.m